# Tool in unix to subtract text files?

Tags: files, text-processing, diff

I have a large file composed of text fields separated by semicolons in the form of a large table. It has been sorted.
I have a smaller file composed of the same text fields. At some point, someone concatenated this file with others and then did a sort to form the large file described above.
I would like to subtract the lines of the small file from the big one (i.e. for each line in the small file, if a matching string exists in the big file, delete that line in the big file).

The file looks roughly like this

```
GenericClass1; 1; 2; NA; 3; 4;
GenericClass1; 5; 6; NA; 7; 8;
GenericClass2; 1; 5; NA; 3; 8;
GenericClass2; 2; 6; NA; 4; 1;
```

etc

Is there a quick classy way to do this or do I have to use awk?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `grep`. Give it the small file as input and tell it to find non-matching lines:

```
grep -vxFf file.txt bigfile.txt > newbigfile.txt
```

The options used are:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)

   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
          is specified by POSIX.)
   -x, --line-regexp
          Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  
          (-x is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Nice, worked perfectly. Thanks very much.

Comment: It's cool that it worked, but it seems to me that it would have been better with the `-x` option as well, in case a line in the smaller file happened to me a substring of another line in main file. Also, it's quite possible that @UlrichSchwarz's answer is faster.

Answer (score 21):

`comm` is your friend:

> NAME
>          comm - compare two sorted files line by line
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
>
> ```
>    With  no  options, produce three-column output.  Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains
>    lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.
>
>    -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
>
>    -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
>
>    -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
> ```

(`comm` will probably have a performance benefit over `grep` since it takes the sortedness into account.)

For example:

```
comm -1 -3 file.txt bigfile.txt > newbigfile.txt
```

Comment: Good point about using comm over grep for sorted lists. This would be a better answer if you gave a specific command line example such as `comm -1 -3 file.txt bigfile.txt > newbigfile.txt`

Comment: I confirm that I tryed grep command reported above with files around 100MB and I got a "killed" error. Trying with comm it finished successfully.

Comment: Command redirection is useful for unsorted files or if you need more than two files: `comm -1 -3 <(sort BAD.txt GOOD.txt) <(sort FILES.txt)`